# Can not run rpm and yum because I deleted libnss by mistake. How to repair it?

Tags: rhel, system-installation, libraries

It's an Amazon RHEL server and I deleted the libnss by running

```
rpm --nodeps -e nss-*;
package-cleanup --cleandupes;
```

Now when I run `rpm` I get an error:

> rpm: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And the same error with `yum`:

> libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I reinstall libnss now?

Comment: Just so we're clear, this is neither rpm's nor yum's fault. There is a reason why dependencies exist, and there is a proper procedure for reinstalling a package that is already installed.

Comment: yes.But I can not run either rpm or yum now.

Comment: Why can't you run `yum` or `rpm`?

Comment: @NasirRiley: Guess what dependency they both have.

Comment: My word. In that case, the only thing that can be done is to open a ticket with Amazon. They probably aren't going to get to it any time soon assuming that they'll even fix it at all.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes. They both depend on it. Thank you!

Comment: @Nasir I very much doubt Amazon will fix this for the OP...

Comment: I doubt it as well as stated at the end of my comment. It's assumed that people using AWS have an understanding of how to use Linux. With that being said, the only real advice that can be given is for the OP and anyone else who might be using the instance to improve their understanding Linux and why it's generally not a good idea to delete or otherwise modify libraries and system files if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to download the necessary packages manually, and extract them using `rpm2cpio` and `cpio` (which don’t need `libnss3`). Go to [the package browser](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser) (using your subscription information) and look for `nss`, then follow the links to download the appropriate version for your RHEL installation. On the server, “install” it by extracting it as follows, as root:

```
cd /
rpm2cpio /path/to/nss-....rpm | cpio -idmv
```

(replacing the path as appropriate, and the `...` with whatever version you have).

This will extract the libraries, and should allow you to use `rpm` and `yum` again. You should then re-install the `nss` package properly using `yum`, along with any other missing dependencies.

Please remember not to use `--no-deps` in future!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above has an issue...
Depending on the Fedora/RHEL version rpm2cpio may depend on libnss3 as well.
You will need another operating system to extract the cpio file from the RPM package (Peazip can do it)